# Altium Netlist Template Syntax

Tags: altium, spice

I have problem understanding how the following expressions in Altium works, inside a component at the `Simulation Spice Functions.IntLib`, by editing a Simulation Model,  `Netlist Template` code:

```
@DESIGNATOR %1 0 VALUE { @EXP1 ?EXP2|
+ @EXP2| ?EXP3|
+ @EXP3| ?EXP4|
+ @EXP4| }
```

In Spice I understand the `E?T:F` is an *if else statement* taking the expression `E` as condition and selecting the `T` or `F` expressions accordingly. But this is not Spice.

The `Netlist Preview` (Spice) code, evaluating some parameters is:

```
E1 V02 0 VALUE { 1 
+ SIN(1 2 100k 0.01m 100k) 
+ 0 
+ 0 }
```

But this actually don't works, meaning this is not accepting the SIN symbol, or something like that.

Where should i find more information about symbols like `@EXP`, `?EXP@EXP`, `@DESIGNATOR` and similar?.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find it Here:

[Altium - Understanding the Netlist Template](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/AMSE/Understanding+the+Netlist+Template).